# Can i allow an empty date field in a form?

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have a Form with in php.  I have it talking and inserting to the the MYsql  database perfectly if i have all fields in the form filled in. Basically i have 3 text fields and 2 dates fields.  i only want to chose either date field instead of both.

I have tried only inserting 1 date and it does not insert in to DB only when i have both dates chosen it works.

Below is the code which works when both date fields are chosen.  i want to be able to only have 1 or the other or both if possible

```
<?php

require('db.php');

//Inserting Data Variables
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
  {
    echo $owner = $_POST['owner'];
    echo $budget = $_POST['budget'];
    echo $status = $_POST['status'];
    echo $s_jan = $_POST['s_jan'];
    echo $s_feb = $_POST['s_feb'];


//Query the database
  $query = "insert into sbook(owner,budget,status,s_jan,s_feb)
  values('$owner','$budget','$status','$s_jan','$s_feb')";

$insert_query = mysqli_query($con, $query);
  }
?>

Here is the form
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>" method="post">
  <label>Owner</label>
  <br />
  <input class="input" type="text" name="owner">
  <br />
  <label>EST Budget:</label><br />
  <input class="input" type="text" name="budget"/>
  <br />
  <label>Status:</label><br />
  <input class="input" type="text" name="status"/>
  <br />
  <label>Jan</label><br />
  <input class="input" type="date" name="s_jan"/>
  <br />
  <label>Feb</label><br />
  <input class="input" type="date" name="s_feb"/>
  <br />

  <p>
      <button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Above is the code which works when both date fields are chosen.  i want to be able to only have 1 date or the other date or both if possible

Comment: Can you clarify about `it does not insert`? Do you get an error?  It doesn't look like your check for errors. Additionally you are open to SQL injections and XSS injections. You also shouldn't `echo` to assign a value.

Comment: Thanks for this info.  I mean when i press submit it does not insert into the database when i only use 1 date. when i use 2 dates it submits in to the database

Comment: @Icelander Check if you date fields in DB are not marked as `NOT NULL`, that means that if you trying to `insert` data without `date fields presented` your DB will ignore this and gave you the error message in you Php statements.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: The [object-oriented interface to `mysqli`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php) is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface where missing a single `i` can cause trouble. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is largely an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: Thanks again in phpmyadmin i have set the NULL field to "Yes" and the default field "NULL" is that right or am i backwards in my thinking

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco Thanks again in phpmyadmin i have set the NULL field to "Yes" and the default field "NULL" is that right or am i backwards in my thinking is that correct

Comment: @Icelander Have you tried to submit your data after changes you made in DB? Does it saves?

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco i have tried again.. I can get on phpmyadmin and go insert and manual insert dates in certain field and works fine. I think it could be the isset function maybe as it does not like empty fields.  i want to be able to have empty field.